# Get bounds of map tile generated by mapbox

Tags: ruby, leaflet, openlayers, mapbox

I've a mobile application that requires the usage of offline maps for areas immediately around certain locations; the plan would be getting a mapbox tile and then surrounding tiles or something of the sort and then rendering them with Leaflet.

This is a multi-part process; first, I use the single coordinate I have on the following Ruby method:

```
def get_tile_number(lat_deg, lng_deg, zoom)
  lat_rad = lat_deg/180 * Math::PI
  n = 2.0 ** zoom
  x = ((lng_deg + 180.0) / 360.0 * n).to_i
  y = ((1.0 - Math::log(Math::tan(lat_rad) + (1 / Math::cos(lat_rad))) / Math::PI) / 2.0 * n).to_i
  {:z => zoom, :x => x, :y =>y}
end
```

Which returns the x, y, z coordinates for a tile, which I can then feed into the mapbox API for a tile image, which I can then use as a source image for leaflet maps... But I don't have any information regarding the boundaries, so the map image can't be used properly.

So, how can I get the information on the boundaries for that map? Is there an easier way of providing offline maps?

Answer (score 3):

You do have the information regarding the boundaries of the map image. You've already computed a point to a tile image. To get the boundaries of the tile image,
here's the code I adapted in JavaScript of the methods in the OpenStreetMaps Wiki:

```
const toDegrees = radians => radians * 180 / Math.PI

const tile2Lon = (x, z) => {
     return (x / Math.pow(2.0, z) * 360.0 - 180)
}

const tile2Lat = (y, z) => {
    let n = Math.PI - (2.0 * Math.PI * y) / Math.pow(2.0, z)
    return (toDegrees(Math.atan(Math.sinh(n))))
}

const tile2BoundingBox = (x, y, zoom) => {

   let bb = {}
   bb.north = tile2Lat(y, zoom)
   bb.south = tile2Lat(y + 1, zoom)
   bb.west = tile2Lon(x, zoom)
   bb.east = tile2Lon(x + 1, zoom)
   return (bb)
}
```

src and in other languages: https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames#Tile_bounding_box